# Windows Bat Find and Replace Line Breaks in Specific Lines

Tags: java, windows, perl, batch-file, fart

I am not a pro developer and need a simple solution.  I have tried using fart.exe within a Windows Bat file to accomplish this, but having trouble finding the exact lines I need to replace line breaks.  In an XML file, here is what I am trying do.

I need to go from this (a few lines in the middle of a larger file):

```
<meta name="xyz:moreinfohere" content="some content"/>
            <meta name="abc:evenmoreinfo" content="more content
and here is where
the problem lies"/>
            <meta name="abc:infoagain" content="this is confusing"/>
            <meta name="xyz:blahblah" content="please help"/>
```

to this:

```
            <meta name="xyz:moreinfohere" content="some content"/>
            <meta name="abc:evenmoreinfo" content="more content&#xa;and here is where&#xa;the problem lies"/>
            <meta name="abc:infoagain" content="this is confusing"/>
            <meta name="xyz:blahblah" content="please help"/>
```

The data filled in these fields will be variable, and this is a fictitious example.  Basically, i am trying to replace the line breaks with the XA code, but only certain lines as you can see.  I have managed to use fart.exe to replace all instances of \n\r but i can't figure out how to only do the needed ones.  Not every line starts with "meta...".  However every line in the files is supposed to end with ">" ...its the only constant/fixed character on every line in the files.  Please help!  I open to anything that works in a standard Windows Bat file (fart, java, etc.)

Comment: Use `powershell.exe` then! not only can it search and replace using regular expessions, or standard strings, it also has built in support for `xml` too.

Comment: @Compo, A standard XML parer won't work here. A compliant parser must replace the line feeds with spaces, which is why the OP wants to change the lines feeds to `&#xa;`. This would cause a parser to return line feed.

Comment: @ikegami This works perfectly! Thank you.  One small question: The result adds the code as `&#xA;`.  Even when i change line 15 in fix.pl, i can't seem to change it.  I need either `&#xa;` or `&#10;`.  How can I update that?

Comment: Those three character references are all equivalent. But literally replace `&#xA;` with one of the others in the code if that's what you want

Comment: lol i was modifying a copy of the pl file.  thanks again man! works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

As you found out, a standard-compliant XML parser will replace a line feed in an attribute's value with a space unless the line feed is encoded using a character reference (e.g. `&#xA;`). ([Reference](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#AVNormalize))

So while I would normally recommend using a proper XML parser, that won't work here because we're trying to fix broken XML (i.e. XML that means something different than what we want it to mean).

We could write a proper XML parser that simply doesn't perform the line feed to space substitution and use that to fix the file, but that's a lot of work. The following is probably sufficient.

Assumptions:

- All attributes values that need fixing use double-quotes (not single-quotes).
- Double-quotes are always found in pairs in the documents to be fixed.

`fix.pl`:

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;

local $/;
while (<>) {
   while (1) {
      /\G ( [^"]+ ) /xgc
         and print $1;

      /\G \z /xgc
         and last;

      /\G ( " [^"]* " ) /xgc
         and do {
            print $1 =~ s/\n/&#xA;/rg;
            next;
         };

      die("Unbalanced quotes");
   }
}
```

Usage:

```
perl fix.pl file_to_fix.xml >fixed_file.xml
```

or

```
perl -i.bak fix.pl file_to_fix.xml
```

The latter modifies the file in-place after making a backup.

After you use this tool, use a file comparison tool (e.g. [Beyond Compare](https://www.scootersoftware.com/)) to make sure the fix was properly applied.